# Error connection pool when setting spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I'm a newbie to create project by spring + hibernate.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer for DB and eclipse for development.

In Spring boot application.properties file we have the following options:

> spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active = 1

When i start project, there are 2 sessions in DB (1 of DB tool).

During application run, error occur

> Occured:: MSG = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException:
>   [https-jsse-nio-8888-exec-2] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a
>   connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:1; busy:1; idle:0;
>   lastwait:10000].

Please give me the way to explain or resolve this error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please try increasing the max.active value

Comment: If I increase max-active value > 1, app can run with 1 user normally.
I want to find out the reason make this error in case value = 1.

Comment: Are you closing all connections after you are done using them?

Comment: I'm using 

getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().close() in finally block.

I am little bit confused in this case. Is this method to close connection properly?

Comment: Or use
DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()) ?

please give me some advise